# Generate texture on image in C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, textures

I have a bitmap image of one color (say green). I want to generate textures on this image. The rendered image will be then saved.

I have tried using convolution matrix but it is not generating any effect as the image is of single color.

Any help or method would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could just use an image editing app to create the effect that you want.  Then just pull that file into whatever you're writing and use it from there.